# Exclude admin user from global password policy

Tags: security, password, user-account, administrator, profile-manager

I have added a global password policy which enforces password rotation for every 90 days. But there are two types of accounts:

1. User Accounts - Enable Password rotation for 90 days
2. Admin Accounts - No Password rotation

I don't want to enable password rotation for Admin Accounts but should enable for User Accounts. Please suggest a clean approach to achieve this.

**Similar Problem:** https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/18574/user-password-policies-on-non-ad-machines

`(Global Policy = All Users except "admin")`

Comment: Why the difference if it is a risk for user accounts then also a risk for admin

Comment: this will be a chef admin user without an UI and behaves like an API user, is it possible to have two different profiles for each user ?

Comment: Note that this is not good practice to force password changes you just get password1 password2 etc (and yes I have done that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers at the link you posted to the JAMF forum gets you most of the way there.

1. [Get all users in the admin group](https://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-from-the-command-line-in-os-x). Running `dscacheutil -q group -a name admin` will work most of the time, but see the linked answer if it gives you trouble.
2. For each user, `pwpolicy -u $USER -clearaccountpolicies` (or set a different policy)